# java packaging problems in compiling with powershell

Tags: java, compilation, packaging, access-modifiers

a very beginner question...
i'm a newbie in programming... just started java and read about packaging... i created i directory called firstproject and put a directory with one class inside of it and a FirstProject source file in the firstproject directory itself.
i made a class in that package directory that has a private string in it and tried to invoke from FirstProject source file but
getting compile error that the string is private... 
i tried changing the string into protected or even public but still getting this error...
this is the error:
 Sticker(String) is not public in Sticker; cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Here is a good table for understanding the access modifiers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private)